# C Redirection causes scanf to not accept input

Tags: c, gcc, clang, scanf

For some reason, scanf isn't working properly after using c redirection to pass input to stdin.
I've tested the same code with no c redirection and it works perfectly fine.

Also, I've tried flushing stdin before doing scanf operations with **fflush(stdin)** and that also did not work.

Running my executable like

```
./3240Assignment0 < test-input.txt
```

The code for running the scanf operation looks as follows

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    fflush(stdin);
    char input[100];
    char *output = "Thank you for your message!";

    puts("Tell me something nice:");
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("%s\n\n", output);
}
```

> The problem is the terminal doesn't give me the opportunity to enter
>   any information or input.

Script of my terminal

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:a0 joemanto$ make test
./3240Assignment0 < test-input.txt
Tell me something nice:
Thank you for your message!

Joes-MacBook-Pro:a0 joemanto$
```

Comment: Why would you expect the program to read from the terminal?  You have explicitly redirected stdin from the file, so `scanf` reads from the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It accepts input, it just accepts input from the file you've told it to accept input from.

You have three options with STDIN:

- `assignment`: Interactive input
- `assignment < input.txt`: Take input from file
- `command | assignment`: Take input from the result of command `command` (pipe)

Since you're using the second form you can't take interactive input as well. It's one input source and one only.